# htaccess 301 custom redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

can anyone help me to set these two redirects?

1)

```
From: old-domain.com/forum/idF-forum-name
To: new-domain.com/forum/forum-name.idF
```

Where idF is a variable number, and "original-name" is a variable phrase

2)

```
From: old-doimain.com/forum/idF-forum-name/idT-thread-name
To: new-domain.com/forum/idF-forum-name/thread-name.idT
```

Where idT is a variable number, and "Thread-name" is a variable phrase.
Somtimes there're urls with another part after idT-thread-name, example:

```
old-doimain.com/forum/idF-forum-name/idT-thread-name/#idP
```

Where idP is a random number. I want to redirect also this kind of URL to "new-domain.com/folder/subfolder/thread-name.idT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1: If there is no .htaccess in `/forum/` directory.**

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ http://new-domain.com/forum/$1/$3.$2 [L,NC,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forum/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ http://new-domain.com/forum/$2.$1 [L,NC,R=302,NE]
```

**Case 2: If there is a .htaccess in `/forum/` directory.**

You can use this code in your `/forum/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ http://new-domain.com/forum/$1/$3.$2 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ http://new-domain.com/forum/$2.$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you sooooo much For the reply. I can create a .htaccess in the forum folder. The problem is that I've to configure also another redirect: all the urls with a different structure from the two written in the post, have to be redirected to the new domain. So, old-domain/* has to be redirected to new-domain.com/*, where * can be any URL different from the two types written in the first post. Is this possible?

Comment: If `/forum/.htaccess` isn't already there then there is no need to create it and take snippet from my `Case 1` above.

Comment: Hello @anubhava, may I ask you how can I add a rule to redirect all URLs in `/forum/`, different from the two listed in the first post, to `https://www.new-domain.com/forum/` ? Thanks! :)

Comment: May I suggest opening a new question as adding new questions on old answers and answering from comments is not possible as it looses formatting and moderators don't like long comments section also.

Comment: ok, i thought that it would have been better to post it here. New question opened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353371/add-rewrite-rule