# Add rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

I've this .htaccess in my /forum/ directory. Now I want to add another rule: all URLs with a format different from the ones specified in these two rules have to be redirected from old-domain.com/forum/* to new-domain.com/forum/.

I need a permanent redirect.

Example of desired redirect:

```
from old-site.com/forum/members/15-username
to new-site.com/forum/
```

Actual .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ http://new-domain.com/forum/$1/$3.$2 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ http://new-domain.com/forum/$2.$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

FYI, these rules are for these redirects:
1)

```
From: old-domain.com/forum/idF-forum-name
To: new-domain.com/forum/forum-name.idF
```

Where idF is a variable number, and "original-name" is a variable phrase

2)

```
From: old-doimain.com/forum/idF-forum-name/idT-thread-name
To: new-domain.com/forum/idF-forum-name/thread-name.idT
```

Where idP is a random number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a new rule at bottom:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^[\w-]+/\d+-[^/]+/?$ http://new-domain.com/forum/ [L,R=302]    

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ http://new-domain.com/forum/$1/$3.$2 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ http://new-domain.com/forum/$2.$1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^ http://new-domain.com/forum/ [L]
```

Comment: /forum/ has to be replaced with new-domain.com/forum/?

Comment: hello @anubhava, I've tested it but it doesn't work. The problem is that for the new URL (look at first post) it matches the first rule. I think that there should be a way to rewrite the two previous rules, specifying that `idF` and `idT` (look at the first post for the meaning) can be **ONLY** numbers. Not sure how to implement it though.

Comment: PS: I need all to be a permanent redirect, just need to change `R=302` to `R=301`, right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Still it doesn't work though. The URL given in the example matches the second rewrite rule, the one with $1/$3.$2 at the end.

Comment: it worked, thanks for your infinite patience!!! Just the last question, if the URL is of a format different from the three specified here, it'll be redirected according to the last rule, right? That last rule, can I add a R=301 there too?

Comment: Done, sorry for the delay and thanks again for your amazing support and patience!